# python sorting a list using lambda function with multiple conditions

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

```
lst = ["g1 act car", "a8 act zoo", "a2 act car"]
```

I want to sort a list such that:

1. Ignoring 1st token of each string, strings are ordered lexicographically
2. If there's a tie, order as per the 1st token

Above list after sorting should be as follows:

```
lst = ["a2 act car", "g1 act car", "a8 act zoo"]
```

I want to write the sorting code in a single line. I can write the code for the 1st condition as follows:

```
lst = sorted(lst, key = lambda x : x.split()[1])
```

How can I combine the second condition as well in this lambda expression?

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```
lst = sorted(lst, key = lambda x : (x.split(None, 1)[1], x.split()[0]))
```

And now:

```
print(lst)
```

Is:

```
['a2 act car', 'g1 act car', 'a8 act zoo']
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it following way:

```
lst = ["g1 act car","a8 act zoo","a2 act car"]
lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x:x.split(None,1)[::-1])
print(lst)
```

Output:

```
['a2 act car', 'g1 act car', 'a8 act zoo']
```

Explanation: `x.split(None,1)` cut at first space (or other seperator), so I get list with *1st token* and *rest*, then I reverse them, so *[rest, 1st token]* are used as `key`, therefore it sorts by *rest* and then *1st token* in case same *rest* appear more than once.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
lst = sorted(lst, key = lambda x : [x.split()[1:], x.split()[0]])
```

And now:

```
lst
```

The result as follow:

```
['a2 act car', 'g1 act car', 'a8 act zoo']
```